# Blazor Sever Identify Size of an Object

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor server app, and I am building a little debug razor components that writes out the size of the objects on my page.  But im not sure how to get the size of an object.

I tried the below but no joy.  Is there something built in c#, I saw something about SizeOf but im not sure how this work or how to implement.

```
private static long GetObjectSize(object obj)
{
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
    var size = ms.Length;
    ms.Dispose();
    return size;
}
```

Any ideas much appreciated

Comment: Explain "no joy". This is about the closes you will get, but probably better wit JSon instead of BinaryFormatter. "the size of an object" is not a valid concept in .net .

Comment: Sure, I get this message - so wasnt sure if Blazor had another preferred method 

System.NotSupportedException: 'BinaryFormatter serialization and deserialization are disabled within this application. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information.'

Comment: Use Json or XML. You will get the sum of the properties, not the (private) fields.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Henk for the great advice, I tweaked the code to:

```
private static long GetObjectSize(object obj)
{
    string serializedString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
    var size = serializedString.Length;
    return size;
}
```